# How do I enable my wireless card? (Dell Inspiron 9400 with Ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: wireless, networking, dell, inspiron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

I am at a complete loss as to what to do here, I spent hours trying to get my wireless card (Broadcom) to work, and have made no progress.

Comment: start by adding to your question the result of the result of the following command: `lspci | grep Network`. This should help giving more specific answers.

Answer (score 2):

The following command should work (if you have an ethernet connection):

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Open the terminal, run the above code and reboot your computer.